# Select related id and map values from primary id

Tags: mysql

Anyone can shed some light? Trying to get related_product_id mapped to product_id and list all values from the product_id.

```
mysql> SELECT p.product_id, p.sku, p.category_color, pcr.color_related_id_1, pcr.id_1_color
    -> FROM product p
    -> LEFT JOIN product_color_related pcr ON p.product_id = pcr.product_id
    -> WHERE p.product_id >= '100'
    -> LIMIT 10;
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
| product_id | sku               | category_color | color_related_id_1 | id_1_color |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
|        100 | HL-010817-FMWP-BK | black          |                101 | silver     |
|        101 | HL-020817-FMWP-BK | silver         |                100 | black      |
|        102 | HL-030817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                100 | black      |
|        103 | HL-040817-FMWP-BK | black          |                104 | silver     |
|        104 | HL-050817-FMWP-BE | silver         |                103 | black      |
|        105 | HL-060817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                103 | black      |
|        106 | HL-070817-FMWP-BK | black          |                107 | brown      |
|        107 | HL-080817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                106 | black      |
|        108 | HL-090817-FMWP-BE | blue           |                106 | black      |
|        109 | HL-100817-FMWP-BK | black          |                110 | brown      |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+
```

So what I would like to achieve is to have new column color_related_sku added for instance and value match to product_id. This case color_related_id_1 101 should have color_related_sku of HL-020817-FMWP-BK and color_related_id_1 100 should have HL-010817-FMWP-BK like illustration below

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
| product_id | sku               | category_color | color_related_id_1 | id_1_color | color_related_sku |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|        100 | HL-010817-FMWP-BK | black          |                101 | silver     | HL-020817-FMWP-BK |
|        101 | HL-020817-FMWP-BK | silver         |                100 | black      | HL-010817-FMWP-BK |
|        102 | HL-030817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                100 | black      | HL-010817-FMWP-BK |
|        103 | HL-040817-FMWP-BK | black          |                104 | silver     | HL-050817-FMWP-BE |
|        104 | HL-050817-FMWP-BE | silver         |                103 | black      | HL-040817-FMWP-BK |
|        105 | HL-060817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                103 | black      | HL-040817-FMWP-BK |
|        106 | HL-070817-FMWP-BK | black          |                107 | brown      | HL-080817-FMWP-TL |
|        107 | HL-080817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                106 | black      | HL-070817-FMWP-BK |
|        108 | HL-090817-FMWP-BE | blue           |                106 | black      | HL-070817-FMWP-BK |
|        109 | HL-100817-FMWP-BK | black          |                110 | brown      | HL-110817-FMWP-BN |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: just add another join with product_color_related to your query, you will figure it out

Comment: Thanks Jorge you were right about it problem solved!

Comment: That's great. So add an answer with your solution or delete this question since there are many with the same subject here on SO. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solution credit to Jorge

```
mysql> SELECT p.product_id, p.sku, p.category_color, pcr.color_related_id_1, pcr.id_1_color, p1.sku
    -> FROM neo_product p
    -> LEFT JOIN neo_product_color_related pcr ON p.product_id = pcr.product_id
    -> LEFT JOIN neo_product p1 ON pcr.color_related_id_1 = p1.product_id
    -> WHERE p.product_id >= '100'
    -> LIMIT 10;
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
| product_id | sku               | category_color | color_related_id_1 | id_1_color | sku               |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|        100 | HL-010817-FMWP-BK | black          |                101 | silver     | HL-020817-FMWP-BK |
|        101 | HL-020817-FMWP-BK | silver         |                100 | black      | HL-010817-FMWP-BK |
|        102 | HL-030817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                100 | black      | HL-010817-FMWP-BK |
|        103 | HL-040817-FMWP-BK | black          |                104 | silver     | HL-050817-FMWP-BE |
|        104 | HL-050817-FMWP-BE | silver         |                103 | black      | HL-040817-FMWP-BK |
|        105 | HL-060817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                103 | black      | HL-040817-FMWP-BK |
|        106 | HL-070817-FMWP-BK | black          |                107 | brown      | HL-080817-FMWP-TL |
|        107 | HL-080817-FMWP-TL | brown          |                106 | black      | HL-070817-FMWP-BK |
|        108 | HL-090817-FMWP-BE | blue           |                106 | black      | HL-070817-FMWP-BK |
|        109 | HL-100817-FMWP-BK | black          |                110 | brown      | HL-110817-FMWP-BN |
+------------+-------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
```